How to install meteor + vue
I'm trying to install / use meteor with vue.
Followed the installation guide step by step, but it's a struggle.
npm install -g meteor
meteor create myapp --vue


Using vue skeleton
=> Errors while creating your project
While selecting package versions: error: Conflict: Constraint webapp@1.13.1 is not satisfied
by webapp 2.0.4. Constraints on package "webapp":

webapp@~2.0.4 <- top level
webapp@2.0.0 <- meteor-base 1.5.2
webapp@2.0.0 <- routepolicy 1.1.2 <- ddp-server 3.0.3 <- ddp 1.4.2 <- allow-deny 2.0.0 <- mongo 2.0.3
webapp@2.0.0 <- routepolicy 1.1.2 <- ddp-server 3.0.3 <- ddp 1.4.2 <- meteor-base 1.5.2
webapp@2.0.0 <- routepolicy 1.1.2 <- webapp 2.0.4 <- meteor-base 1.5.2
webapp@2.0.4 <- ddp-server 3.0.3 <- ddp 1.4.2 <- allow-deny 2.0.0 <- mongo 2.0.3
webapp@2.0.4 <- ddp-server 3.0.3 <- ddp 1.4.2 <- meteor-base 1.5.2
webapp@2.0.0 <- autoupdate 2.0.0 <- hot-code-push 1.0.5 <- hot-module-replacement 0.5.4
webapp@2.0.4 <- mongo 2.0.3
webapp@1.13.1 <- vite:bundler 0.1.9

Conflict: Constraint caching-compiler@1.2.2 is not satisfied by
caching-compiler 2.0.1. Constraints on package "caching-compiler":

caching-compiler@~2.0.1 <- top level
caching-compiler@2.0.0 <- static-html 1.4.0
caching-compiler@2.0.1 <- static-html-tools 1.0.0 <- static-html 1.4.0
caching-compiler@1.2.2 <- vite:bundler 0.1.9

Something has happened while creating your app using git clone. Will
use cached version of skeletons. Error message:  undefined Created a
new Meteor app in 'myapp'.
To run your new app:                             cd myapp
meteor

How to fix this?
I've tried using the installation anyway:
cd myapp
meteor


=> Started proxy.
=> Started HMR server.                         ⚡  You are using meteor-vite v1.12.1 which is not supported by the currently installed
version of jorgenvatle:vite-bundler    Please update it: $ meteor npm
i meteor-vite@2.0
=> Started MongoDB.                            I20241221-07:55:02.842(1)? ⚡   Starting Vite server...
=> Started your app.
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/ I20241221-07:55:03.056(1)? ⚡  Spawned new Meteor-Vite worker process (node:2198101) Warning: The
util._extend API is deprecated. Please use Object.assign() instead.
(Use node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was
created) I20241221-07:55:03.175(1)?   ➜  Local:
http://localhost:5173/ I20241221-07:55:03.176(1)?   ➜  Network: use
--host to expose I20241221-07:55:03.179(1)? ⚡   Meteor-Vite ready for connections! I20241221-07:55:03.189(1)? ⚡   Meteor-Vite ready for
connections!

Updated meteor-vite as requested and called meteor again:
 meteor npm i meteor-vite@2.0
 meteor


=> Started proxy.
=> Started HMR server.
=> Started MongoDB.                            I20241221-07:55:26.660(1)? ⚡   Starting Vite server...
=> Started your app.
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/ W20241221-07:55:26.732(1)? (STDERR) node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:838
W20241221-07:55:26.733(1)? (STDERR)   throw new
ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(packageName, fileURLToPath(base), null);
W20241221-07:55:26.733(1)? (STDERR)         ^
W20241221-07:55:26.733(1)? (STDERR)  W20241221-07:55:26.733(1)?
(STDERR) Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'tsup'
imported from
/home/work/temp/meteor/weaapp/node_modules/meteor-vite/dist/bin/worker.mjs
W20241221-07:55:26.733(1)? (STDERR)     at packageResolve
(node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:838:9) W20241221-07:55:26.733(1)?
(STDERR)     at moduleResolve
(node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:907:18) W20241221-07:55:26.733(1)?
(STDERR)     at defaultResolve
(node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1037:11) W20241221-07:55:26.733(1)?
(STDERR)     at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve
(node:internal/modules/esm/loader:650:12) W20241221-07:55:26.733(1)?
(STDERR)     at #cachedDefaultResolve
(node:internal/modules/esm/loader:599:25) W20241221-07:55:26.734(1)?
(STDERR)     at ModuleLoader.resolve
(node:internal/modules/esm/loader:582:38) W20241221-07:55:26.734(1)?
(STDERR)     at ModuleLoader.getModuleJobForImport
(node:internal/modules/esm/loader:241:38) W20241221-07:55:26.734(1)?
(STDERR)     at ModuleJob._link
(node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:132:49) {
W20241221-07:55:26.734(1)? (STDERR)   code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
W20241221-07:55:26.734(1)? (STDERR) } W20241221-07:55:26.734(1)?
(STDERR)  W20241221-07:55:26.734(1)? (STDERR) Node.js v22.11.0
W20241221-07:55:26.738(1)? (STDERR) Child exited with code: 1 ^C
Blockquote

Which leads to another error.
Tried it on another system as well. Same error.
I'm wondering if anybody is using meteor 3 with vue without any issues.

Here the error is about versions not matching, hence you could manually bump them to satisfies various dependencies, it should be resolved then.

The setup you ended up with "I've tried using the installation anyway" could be workable. I'd suggest to not "Updated meteor-vite as requested" unless the consequences are known, because the message obviously doesn't take them into account. Regarding the errors I'd suggest to report them to meteor

Using Meteor version 3.0.4 worked:
meteor create myapp --vue --release 3.0.4

Also using the latest beta:
meteor create myapp --vue --release 3.1.1-beta.2


Feel free to accept your own answer.
